# Hash Based Data Structure in Java for Collision Calculation

Tags: java, performance, collision

I have started a project on my free time were I'm writing a 2D game engine in Java. One of the more challenging and interesting aspects of such a project is collision detection between sprites on the screen. I have previously written a game engine in C++ were the more naive approach (O(n<sup>2</sup>)) of using a list of all sprites and iterating over it in nested for loops was used. This time I wanted something better in terms of performance, and if possible, also thread safety.

Just as I finished programming this data structure I became aware of the data structure called [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Unlike my *CollisionTable*, it must as far as I understand, be completely cleared and all elements be inserted again for each new frame where the sprites has moved. This is something that I wanted avoid with my CollisionTable.

There are probably a lot of things that can be improved in my CollisionTable, but since my primary reasons for creating it was performance related, I am most curious what you think is good/bad from a performance point of view and what can be improved. With that said, all input is of course welcome!

As far as the JavaDocs go, I know it's a bit verbose and some of the comments describes the internal operation in the methods, which is usually discouraged. But since I wrote the JavaDocs specifically for this code review, I chose not to hold back.

I have included all the code that should be relevant for this data structure here. The entire project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mantono/Dimensions).

```
/**
 * This class implements a data structure with the use of hash functions for
 * {@link Collidable} objects, in order to better perform collision calculations
 * at a lower performance cost. The goal is to reduce the time complexity
 * compared to more naive approaches as usually are O(n<sup>2</sup>).
 * 
 * The CollisionTable does not perform any actual collision detection, it only
 * tries to reduce the amount of elements that are used in the calculation of
 * each collision detection.
 * 
 * Unlike many other more complex data structures/solutions to this problem (not
 * the naive O(n<sup>2</sup>) ones) this implementation is not intended to add
 * or recreate the entire data structure upon each frame, but rather let each
 * {@link CollisionRecord} stay in the data structure until it's considered obsolete.
 *
 */
public class CollisionTable
{
    private final static int[] PRIMES = {23, 53, 97, 193, 389, 769, 1543,
    3079, 6151, 12289, 24593, 49157, 98317, 196613, 393241,
    786433, 1572869, 3145739, 6291469, 12582917, 25165843,
    50331653, 100663319, 201326611, 402653189, 805306457, 1610612741};
    private CollisionSet[] collidableArray;
    private volatile int arraySize = 11;
    private volatile int primeIndex = -1;
    private volatile int count = 0;
    private final long maxTime;
    private final Lock hashLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition hashFinished = hashLock.newCondition();
    private final BlockingQueue<Collidable> incoming = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Collidable>(300);

    /**
     * Constructor for this class.
     * 
     * @param elementCount the expected amount of elements that this data
     * structure will hold.
     * @param maxTime the maximum amount of time in nanoseconds that may elapse
     * before a stored position from a {@link Collidable} object is considered
     * obsolete and will be removed. What value that is appropriate depends on
     * the pace of the {@link Collidable} objects in this game. Setting this
     * value to high will generate less overhead since each
     * {@link CollisionRecord} can be kept for a longer time, but it also
     * increases the chance of missing collisions because the
     * {@link CollisionRecord} instances in this table will not updates its
     * position as often.
     */
    public CollisionTable(final int elementCount, final long maxTime)
    {
        setArraySize(elementCount / 3);
        collidableArray = new CollisionSet[arraySize];
        this.maxTime = maxTime;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for this class. This constructor will use the default array
     * size of 11 upon initialization and set the max time for a
     * {@link CollisionRecord} to 0.1 seconds.
     */
    public CollisionTable()
    {
        this(0, PhysicsEngine.ONE_SECOND / 10);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new to {@link Collidable} to the internal {@link Queue}.
     * 
     * @param collidable the {@link Collidable} object that should be added.
     * @return true if it was successfully added to the queue, else false.
     */
    public boolean add(Collidable collidable)
    {
        return incoming.offer(collidable);
    }

    /**
     * Poll the queue for new {@link Collidable} objects and add it to the
     * table, if it's not empty.
     */
    synchronized void addFromQueue()
    {

        if(incoming.isEmpty())
            return;
        if(size() > arraySize * 5)
            expand();
        while(!incoming.isEmpty())
        {
            addToTable(new CollisionRecord(incoming.poll()), collidableArray);
            count++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the size for this CollisionTable.
     * 
     * @return returns the current amount of {@link CollisionRecord} instances,
     * not taking into account the amount of objects in the queue.
     */
    private int size()
    {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * This method will retrieve all nearby {@link Collidable} objects (wrapped
     * in a {@link CollisionRecord}) that are candidates for a collision with
     * the given parameter {@link Collidable}.
     * 
     * @param collidable the {@link Collidable} we want to find collision
     * candidates for.
     * @param scanPercentage determines how big part of the internal array that
     * should be scanned for likely candidates, where 0 means the absolute
     * minimum scan range and 1 will check the entire array for elements.
     * 
     * Increasing the number will increase the time complexity and reduce the
     * performance but also reduce the chance of missing any collisions. Setting
     * this to 1 will give a time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>) if this method
     * is called for every {@link Collidable}, but with more overhead than a
     * simple double for-loop. It is recommended that this parameter is set as
     * low as possible, as long as no collisions are missed
     * @return a set containing {@link CollisionRecord} of all collision
     * candidates.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>scanPercentage</code> is &lt; 0
     * or &gt; 1.
     */
    public Set<CollisionRecord> getCollidables(final Collidable collidable, float scanPercentage)
    {
        if(scanPercentage < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter scanPercentage cannot be negative.");
        if(scanPercentage > 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter scanPercentage cannot be greater than 1.");

        final Set<CollisionRecord> collisionCandidates = new HashSet<CollisionRecord>();

        hashLock.lock();
        waitForHash();

        final int hashRadius = Math.round(arraySize * scanPercentage);

        final int index = hashIndex(collidable, collidableArray);
        for(int i = index - hashRadius; i <= index + hashRadius; i++)
        {
            if(i < 0)
                i = 0;
            final Set<CollisionRecord> set = collidableArray[i % collidableArray.length];
            if(set != null)
                collisionCandidates.addAll(removeObsolete(set));
        }

        hashLock.unlock();

        return collisionCandidates;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all instance of {@link CollisionRecord} which is considered
     * obsolete. If the {@link CollisionRecord} is considered obsolete but
     * {@link Collidable#isReadyToRemove()} returns false, then it will be added
     * to the queue in order to receive a new {@link CollisionRecord}.
     * 
     * @param collisionCandidates a set of {@link CollisionRecord}.
     * @return the remaining {@link CollisionRecord} instances which are not
     * considered obsolete.
     */
    private Set<CollisionRecord> removeObsolete(Set<CollisionRecord> collisionCandidates)
    {
        final Iterator<CollisionRecord> recordIterator = collisionCandidates.iterator();
        while(recordIterator.hasNext())
        {
            final CollisionRecord record = recordIterator.next();
            if(record.isObsolete(maxTime) || record.getCollidable().isReadyToRemove())
            {
                recordIterator.remove();
                count--;
                if(!record.getCollidable().isReadyToRemove())
                    add(record.getCollidable());
            }
        }

        return collisionCandidates;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a {@link CollisionRecord} to array of {@link CollisionSet}.
     * 
     * @param record the {@link CollisionRecord} that should be added.
     * @param array the array that the record should be added to.
     * @return true if it was successfully added to the {@link CollisionSet} at
     * the given array index, else false.
     */
    private boolean addToTable(CollisionRecord record, CollisionSet[] array)
    {
        try
        {
            hashLock.lock();
            final int index = hashIndex(record.getCollidable(), array);
            if(index >= array.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Illegal state: Trying to insert in index " 
             + index + " but size of array is " + array.length + "(" + arraySize + ")\n");
            if(array[index] == null)
                array[index] = new CollisionSet();
            return array[index].add(record);
        }
        finally
        {
            hashLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Expands the size of the internal array.
     */
    private void expand()
    {
        hashLock.lock();
        advanceTotNextPrime();
        rehashTable();
        hashFinished.signalAll();
        hashLock.unlock();
    }

    /**
     * Shrinks the size of the internal array. This method is currently not
     * used.
     */
    private void shrink()
    {
        hashLock.lock();
        previousPrime();
        rehashTable();
        hashFinished.signalAll();
        hashLock.unlock();
    }

    /**
     * Waits for this class {@link ReentrantLock} to be released that is locking
     * the internal array.
     * 
     * A more compact version of {@link Condition#await()} with exception
     * handling taken care of, so this will not have to repeated every time
     * <code>hashFinished.await()</code> would be called.
     */
    private void waitForHash()
    {
        try
        {
            while(collidableArray.length != arraySize)
                hashFinished.await();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            hashLock.unlock();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new array when the conditions require it change size. All
     * elements will have to be rehashed to fit in the new arrays size.
     */
    private void rehashTable()
    {
        final CollisionSet[] rehashedArray = new CollisionSet[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < collidableArray.length; i++)
        {
            final CollisionSet set = collidableArray[i];
            if(set != null)
                for(CollisionRecord record : set)
                    if(!record.getCollidable().isReadyToRemove())
                        addToTable(record, rehashedArray);
        }

        collidableArray = rehashedArray;
    }

    /**
     * Computes the hash for a {@link Collidable} and converts it to an index
     * matching the size of an array.
     * 
     * @param collidable the {@link Collidable} to compute the hash for.
     * @param array the array which length has to be taken into consideration.
     * @return an index based on the hash for the {@link Collidable} and is
     * within bounds for the array.
     */
    private int hashIndex(Collidable collidable, Object[] array)
    {
        final int hash = computeHash(collidable.getCenterOfSprite());
        final int index = Math.abs(hash % array.length);
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * This is where the magic happens.
     * 
     * Computes the two dimensional data of a {@link Coordinate2D} (x and y
     * value) so it can be sorted into a one dimensional array. This is done by
     * measuring the distance from the given coordinate and three other
     * coordinates on the screen and with those variables compute a hash. The
     * purpose of this hash is that it should turn out the same (or very
     * similar) for coordinates that are located close to each other.
     * 
     * @param screenCoordinates the coordinates that will be computed.
     * @return the hash for this coordinate.
     */
    private int computeHash(Coordinate2D screenCoordinates)
    {
        final double d1 = screenCoordinates.distance(0, 0);
        final double d2 = screenCoordinates.distance(0, GameSettings.heightWindow);
        final double d3 = screenCoordinates.distance(GameSettings.widthWindow, GameSettings.heightWindow);
        final double diff = d1 - d3;
        final double d2Squared = Math.sqrt(d2 + 1);

        final double result = diff / d2Squared;

        return (int) result;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the array size (on next rehash of table) to the next greater
     * prime number.
     */
    private void advanceTotNextPrime()
    {
        arraySize = PRIMES[++primeIndex];
    }

    /**
     * Changes the array size (on next rehash of table) to the next lesser prime
     * number.
     */
    private void previousPrime()
    {
        arraySize = PRIMES[--primeIndex];
    }

    /**
     * Finds the next prime number that is equal or greater to the given
     * argument, and sets the future array size to that number.
     * 
     * @param initialApproximateArraySize the number that should be compared to.
     */
    private void setArraySize(int initialApproximateArraySize)
    {
        if(initialApproximateArraySize < 11)
            return;
        for(int i = 0; i < PRIMES.length; i++)
        {
            if(PRIMES[i] >= initialApproximateArraySize)
            {
                arraySize = PRIMES[i];
                primeIndex = i;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Class CollisionSet is simply a class that extends TreeSet, this is a work around, since arrays in Java and generics don't work together.
2. CollisionRecord is basically a Collidable with a timestamp.
3. Collidable (interface) is a form of Sprite that has the ability to collide with other Collidables.
4. Coordinate2D can be considered equivalent to Java FX Point, except it's not immutable.

```
public class CollisionRecord implements Comparable<CollisionRecord>
{
    private final Collidable collidable;
    private final long timestamp;

    public CollisionRecord(final Collidable collidable)
    {
        this.collidable = collidable;
        this.timestamp = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public Collidable getCollidable()
    {
        return collidable;
    }

    public long getTimestamp()
    {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public boolean isObsolete(long nanoSeconds)
    {
        return System.nanoTime() - timestamp > nanoSeconds;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CollisionRecord o)
    {
        return (int) ((this.timestamp - o.timestamp) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

I think this is all the code that is relevant for the data structure.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answers.